# "being" versus "is"

Tags: word-difference

I made a search for "flag of switzerland" on google and i encountered with this passage.

- *It is one of only two square sovereign-state flags, the other **being** the flag of Vatican City.*

I am unable to understand why **being** is used after the comma. I think it sould be like:

- *It is one of only two square sovereign-state flags, the other **is** the flag of Vatican City.*

What is the difference between the two sentences? Is my version correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

***Being*** in your first sentence is used correctly as the participle of the verb *to be* in a *present participle clause.* Another example of this usage might be:

> **Being** tall, I bent over to get through the door.

This use of **being** is seldom encountered in natural speech, but is more common in formal writing, as in the reference text cited in your example. One less formal way to express the thought might be to create two complete sentences:

> It is one of only two square sovereign-state flags. The other is the flag of Vatican City.

As JamesK says, a semi-colon might also be used:

> It is one of only two square sovereign-state flags; the other is the flag of Vatican City.

Your own second sentence, though, uses a comma in what we call a *[comma splice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice)* It creates a *[run-on sentence,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence)* in which two main clauses (clauses which can stand alone as complete sentences) are combined, and this is considered poor usage in most cases.

Answer (score -2):

In the second sentence, both phrases are complete sentences. As complete sentences the use of a comma is questionable, it is a "comma splice". Using a semicolon is possible "... sovereign-state flags; the other ..."

The first sentence, which uses an participle phrase "being the flag..." which describes "the other"

So your version is correct, (but the punctuation may be disputed). The first version is also correct, and has almost the same meaning.

Comment: So now we teach new learners that a run-on sentence is _correct?_ -1.

Comment: It is an orthographic detail. A recent "rule" that has little basis in tradition. Go and read Jane Austen

Comment: I _intentionally_ refrained from using the word _rule,_ once our new learners attain the fluency of Jane Austen, let them write lovely flowing fiction in their own voices, at this early stage, let's encourage them to hew to a reasonable standard,

Comment: I downvoted this because it does not really explain the use of *being* but seems to focus on the punctuation. I think this is a 'mis-emphasis'.